# Find Control returns Null Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having an asp .Net page where i have a labe named rowId

```
      protected void testResultsGridView_onRowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        GridViewRow row = testResultsGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Int32 id = Int32.Parse(((Label)row.FindControl("rowId")).Text);
        String Cause = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("Cause")).SelectedValue;
        String comment = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("comment")).Text;
        String check = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("check")).Text;
        String reRunStatus = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("Status")).SelectedValue;
        String subCategory = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("Category")).SelectedValue;


        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in testResultsGridView.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbSelect");
            if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
            {
                 id = Int32.Parse(((Label)gvrow.FindControl("rowId")).Text); ;

                UpdateTestCase(id, rootCause, subCategory, comment, RTC, reRunStatus);

            }
        }
        testResultsGridView.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }
```

In this case first find control of rowId return values and second one inside selected scheckbox returns null. I am not even adding any control dynamically. What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

GridView not only have DataRows but has other row types like header, foooter. Your control are in DataRow type. You need to check if the row where you are trying to find `rowId` is a `DataRow` as there are other row types which would not have conntrol with `id` `rowId` You can find more about `RowType` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to find control where `RowType` is `DataRow`.

```
if(gvrow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
```

**Why it works for first time**

It works for first time because the event onRowUpdating is fired on row having type DataRow.

**Why it does not work for second time**

For second time you are iterating the Rows of GridView which have other row types as well. If you debug the code you will see you will get null when `RowType` is not `DataRow`.

You code would be

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in testResultsGridView.Rows)
{
   if(gvrow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbSelect");
        if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
        {
             id = Int32.Parse(((Label)gvrow.FindControl("rowId")).Text); ;

            UpdateTestCase(id, rootCause, subCategory, comment, RTC, reRunStatus);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done it. It turns out it is indeed a data row

Comment: Do you get null from FindControl for rowId, what about finding other controls?

Comment: I am not able to get any control from gvrow

Comment: Did you use me code with condition  if(gvrow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)?

Comment: Add your GridView HTML in question and show how and where you bind the data to GridView